# Proof of Liouville's Theorem (Check)

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification

**Liouville's Theorem**: If $f(z)$ entire, bounded function, then is a constant.

Let $a,b$ be any 2 points in the Complex plane. Using the Cauchy Integral formula:

$$f(b)-f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(z)dz}{(z-b)}-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(z)dz}{(z-a)}$$ where R is the radius of a circle that properly contains $a,b$.

Therefore,

$$f(b)-f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(z)(b-a)dz}{(z-b)(z-a)}$$

Since:

$$|\frac{f(z)(b-a)}{(z-b)(z-a)}|\leq \frac{M|b-a|}{(R-|b|)(R-|a|)}$$

Using ML formula:

$$|f(b)-f(a)|=\frac{1}{2\pi}|\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(z)(b-a)dz}{(z-b)(z-a)}|\leq \frac{M|b-a|}{(R-|b|)(R-|a|)} R$$

Take $R\rightarrow\infty$.

Hence, $|f(a)-f(b)|=0 \Rightarrow f(a)=f(b)$

Is this proof Valid?

Comment: What part do you have doubts about, and why?

Comment: You left out the $\frac 1{2\pi i}$ in a few places...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine, other than that the final $2\pi$ shouldn't be there (it cancels with the one that you forgot…). I would have added a thing that you left implicit:$$\bigl|f(b)-f(a)\bigr|\leqslant\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{M|b-a|}{(R-|b|)(R-|a|)}R=0,$$and therefore $f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: The OP stated "Take $R\to\infty$."  The OP likely assumed that the reader understands that the limit is $0$.

Comment: @MarkViola I have no doubt about that. All I wrote was that I would have mentioned it explicitly.

Comment: That's fine.  It wasn't evident that you had seen that one statement.  I've glossed over passages as explicit and upfront as possible.  ;-)